# Largest subsequence in a random ordering

Tags: probability, permutations

Suppose I have the set $[n]$ and I arrange this uniformly at random into a sequence, which I can represent as a map $\pi_n:[n]\to [n]$. Now I want to find, on expectation, the largest possible subsequence in $\pi$ (not necessarily consecutive) that is increasing.

In other words, given a $\pi_n$, there exists a maximum value of $m\leq n$ such that there exists $x_1,x_2,...,x_m\in[n]$ which are increasing and $\pi_n(x_1),\pi_n(x_2),...,\pi_n(x_m)$ is also increasing. I want to find the expected value of this $m$ where the expectation is over the uniform distribution of $\pi_n$ 's.

Also, I arrived at this problem while studying an algorithmic problem. So I am not too keen on the exact expression, a constant approximation would suffice - but an exact expression would be just as good. What I mean is that I would be happy if I could know if this is of the order of $n$ or maybe of the order of $\sqrt{n}$ or maybe of the order of $\log n$.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as 'Ulam's problem'. The expectation of the longest increasing subsequence in a random permutation is of order $2\sqrt{n}$. See this paper (and references) for more information https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1999-12-04/S0894-0347-99-00307-0/S0894-0347-99-00307-0.pdf

Comment: Ah that's nice. Also are there estimates known if I want an increasing sequence starting at the first number?

Comment: I don't know about this. However, we can do the following: let the $l_N$ be the length of the longest increasing subsequence in a random permutation and $l^*_N$ be the length of the longest increasing subsequence that starts at the first number. Note that under condition $\pi(1)=k$ the variable $l^*_N$ has the same distribution as $l_{N−k}$ (we can throw away all elements which are less than $k$; everything is equidistributed). One can conclude that $\mathbb{E}[l_N^*]=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\mathbb{E}[{l_{N-k+1}}]$ and obtain estimates using this equality.